# How to open the SD card directory to select a file with Flutter?

Tags: android, dart, flutter

The function I want to achieve is to open the SD card directory after clicking a button, then I can select a PPT file, it will call the machine to view the PPT software to open, how can I achieve this function?

Comment: try this - https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_document_picker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @anmol.majhail mentioned in a comment earlier, use the [flutter_document_picker](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_document_picker) plugin:

```dart
final String pptPath = await FlutterDocumentPicker.openDocument(
  params: FlutterDocumentPickerParams(
    allowedFileExtensions: ['ppt'],
    allowedMimeType: 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint',
    allowedUtiTypes: ['com.microsoft.powerpoint.​ppt'],
  )
);
```

Once you have the file path, use the [android_intent](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/android_intent) plugin to open it in a viewer app such as [WPS Office](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cn.wps.moffice_eng):

```dart
if (platform.isAndroid) {
  final AndroidIntent intent = AndroidIntent(
    action: 'action_view',
    data: Uri.file(pptPath).toString(),
    arguments: {},
    package: 'cn.wps.moffice_eng', // optional
  );
  await intent.launch();
}
```